Encode is giving error as "The data couldn't be written because it isn't in the correct format"
I have one API where based on parameters data is changing.
Response 1

{
  "success": true,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "errorLst": [],
  "succcessMessage": null,
  "resultData": [
    {
      "plotSize": 1,
      "equationValue": null
    },
    {
      "plotSize": 2,
      "equationValue": "*1.5"
    },
    {
      "plotSize": 3,
      "equationValue": "*2.5"
    }
  ]
}

Response 2
{
  "success": true,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "errorLst": [],
  "succcessMessage": null,
  "resultData": [
    {
      "plotSize": 4,
      "equationValue": "*4"
    },
    {
      "plotSize": 5,
      "equationValue": "*5.5"
    },
    {
      "plotSize": 6,
      "equationValue": "*6.5"
    }
  ]
}

I parse the API data and try to convert the base model data to my actual mode data:
let myEndPoint = EndPoint(modelType: PlotModel.self)
self.plotModelModel = convertToModel(baseModelResponse: inner_apiResponse, endpoint: myEndPoint) as? PlotModel ?? PlotModel()

inner_apiResponse is nothing but the data I get from API parsed as BaseModel
Model I have is as below:
struct PlotModel : Codable {
    var success : Bool?
    var statusCode : Int?
    var succcessMessage : String?
    
    var resultData : [InnerPlotData]?
    
}

struct InnerPlotData : Codable {
    var plotSize : Int?
    var equationValue : String?
}

I am using below function to convert the base model to my model:
func convertToModel<T : Codable>(baseModelResponse : BaseModel, endpoint : EndPoint<T>) -> Any {
    
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let jsonData = try encoder.encode(baseModelResponse)
            if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
                    do {
                        let localModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(endpoint.modelType.self, from: data)
                        return localModel
                    } catch {
                        print("Error parsing JSON:", error)
                        return makeErrorBaseModel()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Invalid JSON string")
                    return makeErrorBaseModel()
                }
            } else {
                return makeErrorBaseModel()
            }
        } catch let decodingError as DecodingError {
            switch decodingError {
                case .typeMismatch(_, let c), .valueNotFound(_, let c), .keyNotFound(_, let c), .dataCorrupted(let c):
                    "error.debugDescription=c===\(c.debugDescription)".printLog()
                    return makeErrorBaseModel()
            }
        } catch {
            "error.debugDescription==\(error.localizedDescription)".printLog()
            return makeErrorBaseModel()
        }
    } catch {
        return makeErrorBaseModel()
    }
    
}

Model I have is as below:
struct BaseModel : Codable {
    var success : Bool?
    var statusCode : Int?
    var succcessMessage : String?
    
    var resultData : AnyCodable?
    
}

@objcMembers final class AnyCodable: NSObject, Codable {
    
    let value: Any?
    
    init(_ value: Any?) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self.value = value
        } else if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            self.value = value
        } else if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self.value = value
        } else if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            self.value = value
        } else if let value = try? container.decode(Float.self) {
            self.value = value
        } else if container.decodeNil() {
            self.value = nil
        } else if let value = try? container.decode([String: AnyCodable].self) {
            self.value = value.mapValues { $0.value }
        } else if let value = try? container.decode([AnyCodable].self) {
            self.value = value.map { $0.value }
        }  else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(
                in: container,
                debugDescription: "Invalid value cannot be decoded"
            )
        }
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch value {
            case let bool as Bool:
                try container.encode(bool)
            case let int as Int:
                try container.encode(int)
            case let float as Float:
                try container.encode(float)
            case let double as Double:
                try container.encode(double)
            case let string as String:
                try container.encode(string)
            case let array as [Any?]:
                try container.encode(array.map { AnyCodable($0) })
            case let dictionary as [String: Any?]:
                try container.encode(dictionary.mapValues { AnyCodable($0) })
            case let encodable as Encodable:
                try encodable.encode(to: encoder)
            default:
                let context = EncodingError.Context(codingPath: container.codingPath, debugDescription: "AnyEncodable value cannot be encoded")
                throw EncodingError.invalidValue(value ?? "InvalidValue", context)
        }
    }
}

Response 2 is working fine, however Response 1 is giving error as below:
error.debugDescription==The data couldn’t be written because it isn’t in the correct format.

Exception is thrown at let jsonData = try encoder.encode(baseModelResponse) line.
Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?
Minimal Code to check
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/08ebea0e519f58023444c36727e4afdc20240820150159/adf188

After further check as per vadian, I found that in func encode, I get exception as below.
invalidValue("InvalidValue", Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "resultData", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), _JSONKey(stringValue: "equationValue", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "AnyEncodable value cannot be encoded", underlyingError: nil))
However the equationValue is of type String as mentioned in the model

If you notice, equationValue is null in the first row and AnyCodable is setting it's type as Any and next place I am getting data as String which is why I am getting this error. May be...

Could you provide a MRE?

@JoakimDanielson : Ok, I will do today when get free...

Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just decode directly the response body, attempting to get a PlotModel? Or, maybe use a generic Response<T> conforming to Decodable, where T is the decodable type of whatever is resultData.  You then can "unwrap" the actual data of type T with the property resultData and call it a day ;)  Means, you don't need anything else - just this Result<T>.  Just ensure T also conforms to decodable.

In a Codable environment always print theerror rather than its localizedDescription. You throw away the real descriptive error.

@JoakimDanielson : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/08ebea0e519f58023444c36727e4afdc20240820150159/adf188 Please check for apiURLString and logs for errors...

@vadian : I have updated question with a code link... Can you check if possible...

@vadian : thank you for saving... I get error as "invalidValue("InvalidValue", Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "resultData", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), _JSONKey(stringValue: "equationValue", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "AnyEncodable value cannot be encoded", underlyingError: nil))"

@JoakimDanielson : In my code I didn't add var equationValue : String? inside RentEstimatorInnerVisibleConfigPlotSizesModel model. You can add to check further. I didn't add as I don't want to use it as it's useless for me. Also check above message to check the reason for exception...

The error means what it says: "AnyEncodable value cannot be encoded". You are fighting the framework. Codable does not support Any.  Is traditional JSONSerialization not an option?

The value that's failing is:
  "equationValue": null

You forgot to include a case for that:
case nil:
    try container.encodeNil()

A better approach for you may be a JSON type that can hold "something that can be expressed in JSON" without resorting to Any.

Thank you for quick reply.. I will look into it and get back to you...

Thank you for this, it's working fine...
